# Android Live wallpaper like screen wash

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I need your help. I need to create live wallpaper like this : [Bikini girl!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=1LXDtGEfOeQ#!)
If you can point me in the right direction it will be wonderful. Also, I want to know is this a video file or is it an animated gif or something else. I saw a simple tutorial for live wallpaper, but didn't find anywhere something like this. If you can give me some direction, like what I need to do first, what to use or some code it will be great.
Thanks again!!!

Comment: You have to work with SurfaceView and Canvas. I also suggest you to read the article on Android Developer, that is really clear to understand how to develop [LiveWallpapers](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/live-wallpapers.html)

Comment: Okey, but can you tell me is it a video or a animated gif? I will start from your sugestion and move on...

Comment: I've never worked with LiveWallpapers directly, but GIFs are only 256 colors, so it's really hard to believe that a LW like the one you need to create is made on a poor quality image like GIF

Comment: Okey...thanks for your time... post this as a answer and if nobody put something that will help me i will claim your answer as true... Thanks again Mangusto.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to work with SurfaceView and Canvas. I also suggest you to read the article on Android Developer, that is really clear to understand how to develop [LiveWallpapers](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/live-wallpapers.html).

I've never worked with LiveWallpapers directly, but GIFs are only 256 colors, so it's really hard to believe that a LiveWallpaper like the one you need to create is made on a poor quality image like GIF.